# External JavaScript file will not update HTML element attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML file, and a JavaScript file in the same directory. I have variables in the JS file specifically for easier access to modify. My goal is to have the page load those variables and use them to change element attributes. In Inspect Element, if I click the JavaScript reference in the < head > tag, it takes me to the JavaScript file as it should, so I don't understand why the HTML file won't load it. I feel like there's something small that I'm missing so if you could point it out for me, that would be great. Thanks.

`links.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Lil Ses &amp; Rony</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="links.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://linkupapp.org/links.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="jsUpdate()">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <img class="logo" src="links logo.jpg" />

        <!-- Name -->
        <h2>Lil Ses & Rony</h2>

        <a name="spotify" href="">no value</a>
        <a name="appleMusic" href="">no value</a>
        <a name="youTube" href="">no value</a>
        <a name="soundCloud" href="">no value</a>
        <a name="twitter" href="">no value</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

`links.js`

```js
var songTitle = "Runaway";
var spotify = "spotify:track:1TsKB26M4Tz2JrC56uZo2z";
var appleMusic = "https://music.apple.com/ca/album/runaway/1502683420?i=1502683423";
var youTube = "https://youtu.be/3Zmm4e3ysjY";
var soundCloud = "https://soundcloud.com/user-887966595/runaway-prod-secret";
var twitter = "https://www.twitter.com/lilsesandrony";

var links = {
    spotify : {
        title : songTitle + " (Spotify)",
        link : spotify
    },

    appleMusic : {
        title : songTitle + " (Apple Music)",
        link : appleMusic
    },

    youTube : {
        title : songTitle + " (YouTube)",
        link : youTube
    },

    soundCloud : {
        title : songTitle + " (SoundCloud)",
        link : soundCloud
    },

    twitter : {
        title : "Twitter",
        link : twitter
    }
};

function jsUpdate() {
    var ref = {
        spotify : document.getElementsByName("spotify"),
        appleMusic : document.getElementsByName("appleMusic"),
        youTube : document.getElementsByName("youTube"),
        soundCloud : document.getElementsByName("soundCloud"),
        twitter : document.getElementsByName("twitter"),
    };

    ref.spotify.innerHtml = links.spotify.title;
    ref.spotify.href = links.spotify.link;

    ref.appleMusic.innerHtml = links.appleMusic.title;
    ref.appleMusic.href = links.appleMusic.link;

    ref.youTube.innerHtml = links.youTube.title;
    ref.youTube.href = links.youTube.link;

    ref.soundCloud.innerHtml = links.soundCloud.title;
    ref.soundCloud.href = links.soundCloud.link;

    ref.twitter.innerHtml = links.twitter.title;
    ref.twitter.href = links.twitter.link;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an array so replace

```
var ref = {
    spotify : document.getElementsByName("spotify"),
    appleMusic : document.getElementsByName("appleMusic"),
    youTube : document.getElementsByName("youTube"),
    soundCloud : document.getElementsByName("soundCloud"),
    twitter : document.getElementsByName("twitter"),
};
```

With

```
var ref = {
    spotify : document.getElementsByName("spotify")[0],
    appleMusic : document.getElementsByName("appleMusic")[0],
    youTube : document.getElementsByName("youTube")[0],
    soundCloud : document.getElementsByName("soundCloud")[0],
    twitter : document.getElementsByName("twitter")[0],
};
```

Also it's `innerHTML` and not `innerHtml`.

You can vastly improve your code by using `document.getElementById` and a for loop instead of `document.getElementsByName`:

```
function jsUpdate() {
    for (var service in links) {
        var el = document.getElementById(service)

        el.innerHTML = links[service].title
        el.href = links[service].link
    }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<a id="spotify" href="">no value</a>
<a id="appleMusic" href="">no value</a>
<a id="youTube" href="">no value</a>
<a id="soundCloud" href="">no value</a>
<a id="twitter" href="">no value</a>
```

Comment: Using id instead of name to target elements might be better in this case, since you don't want a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet with the issue fixed, which is that `documents.getElementsByName()` returns an array of elements, even when there is only one in the page with that name.

Therefore, knowing this, you can just reference the first element with `document.getElementsByName('name')[0]`

But to be honest, a better design here is to use the `id` attribute instead of `name`, and the corresponding `document.getElementById('id')`. `id` is supposed to be unique, therefore `document.getElementById()` only returns a single element that you can just use straight away like you wanted to.

```js
var songTitle = "Runaway";
var spotify = "spotify:track:1TsKB26M4Tz2JrC56uZo2z";
var appleMusic = "https://music.apple.com/ca/album/runaway/1502683420?i=1502683423";
var youTube = "https://youtu.be/3Zmm4e3ysjY";
var soundCloud = "https://soundcloud.com/user-887966595/runaway-prod-secret";
var twitter = "https://www.twitter.com/lilsesandrony";

var links = {
    spotify : {
        title : songTitle + " (Spotify)",
        link : spotify
    },

    appleMusic : {
        title : songTitle + " (Apple Music)",
        link : appleMusic
    },

    youTube : {
        title : songTitle + " (YouTube)",
        link : youTube
    },

    soundCloud : {
        title : songTitle + " (SoundCloud)",
        link : soundCloud
    },

    twitter : {
        title : "Twitter",
        link : twitter
    }
};


  var ref = {
      spotify : document.getElementsByName("spotify")[0],
      appleMusic : document.getElementsByName("appleMusic")[0],
      youTube : document.getElementsByName("youTube")[0],
      soundCloud : document.getElementsByName("soundCloud")[0],
      twitter : document.getElementsByName("twitter")[0],
  };

  ref.spotify.innerHTML = links.spotify.title;
  ref.spotify.href = links.spotify.link;

  ref.appleMusic.innerHTML = links.appleMusic.title;
  ref.appleMusic.href = links.appleMusic.link;

  ref.youTube.innerHTML = links.youTube.title;
  ref.youTube.href = links.youTube.link;

  ref.soundCloud.innerHTML = links.soundCloud.title;
  ref.soundCloud.href = links.soundCloud.link;

  ref.twitter.innerHTML = links.twitter.title;
  ref.twitter.href = links.twitter.link;
```

```html
<a name="spotify" href="">no value</a>
<a name="appleMusic" href="">no value</a>
<a name="youTube" href="">no value</a>
<a name="soundCloud" href="">no value</a>
<a name="twitter" href="">no value</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. marco-a's answer provided more detail regarding a second mistake I made. I appreciate your help though.